# Is there a way to fix a conflict between pgf-pie and tkz-euclide error undefined control sequence @t noexpand?

Tags: tkz-euclide, pgf-pie

I am using Overleaf.
If I load both `tkz-euclide` package and the `pgf-pie` package, I get the following error for each pie graph:
pgfpie @t \noexpand and the graphs do not display the labels of the sectors.

With just the `pgf-pie` package Without the `tkz-euclide` package, the labels on the pie graph are fine.  Is there a way to have both with no errors.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
% \printanswers
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{questions}
\question first question

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[color={black!10, black!20, black!30, black!40}]
{10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\pie[pos={8,0}, color=blue!20] {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compatibility problem between `pgf-pie` v0.5 or older and tikz library `babel`. `tkz-euclide` loads `tkz-base`, and the latter package loads `tikz` and its `babel` library.

- Good news: It has been resolved in `pgf-pie` v0.6 released in 2021 Jul, see the related issue [pgf-pie#10](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie/issues/10), PR [pgf-pie#11](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie/issues/11), and the ["Bug fixes" part of release note](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf-pie/releases/tag/0.6).
- Bad news: Overleaf's texlive 2021 still uses v0.5. To have access to `pgf-pie` v0.6 or newer, I guess you need to wait for overleaf to upgrade to texlive 2022.

Apart from manually uploading package files, you can use the following patch as a quick workaround for `pgf-pie` v0.5.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % or just \usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\usepackage{xpatch}
% workaround for pgfpie v0.5, provided by Overleaf's texlive 2021
\makeatletter
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{pgf-pie}{2021/07/30}{}{%
  \xpretocmd\pgfpie@@pie
    {\scope[handle active characters in nodes=false]}
    {}{\PatchFailed}%
  \xapptocmd\pgfpie@@pie
    {\endscope}
    {}{\PatchFailed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pie {10/A, 20/B, 30/C, 40/D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In a few days I will put on my site the  version 4 of tkz-euclide which does not load tkz-base anymore

Comment: @AlainMatthes No hurry (for this issue). Every texlive version on overleaf is more like a version-locked mirror/container (except for fatal bug fixes I guess) so most normal package updates will not be included in time.